# ACS712 connected to MCP3008 ADC

Tags: arduino

I try to measure my ACS712(5A) with an MCP3008 with very limited success to wrong fluctuating values.
Both ACS and ADC are powered with the same 5v power (MP1584 breadboard) and output of the ACS is directly connected to ch0 of the MCP3008 no resistor and no capacitor.
With no current on inputs of the ACS its input is 2.5v on my DMM but reading of the MCP3008 shows fluctuating values of 480-530 counts.. I can't explain why, could someone help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have an oscilloscope, I'd like you to check ACS712's output (MCP3008's input) to see if some noise is added to the average 2.5V.

Comment: I guess it is normal. There is some small alternating current on the AC wire

Comment: Thanks for your answers. No, i don't have any oscilloscope but it seems that the MP1584 is not providing a very stable and not noisy power. I'll add some capacitors (i tried 220uf with small success) around 1000uf and 100nf and see what happens... Keep you aware